# Can you make an MVC Post action only accept form data and not querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP MVC 5 and I have an action on my controller as such

```
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult MyMethod(string param)
{
    // Action code here
}
```

I need this to accept it's data "param" only from form data, and not from a query string.

So something like this should work

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/Home/MyMethod">
    <input type="hidden" name="param" value="MyValue" />
    <input type="submit" value="Post with token" />
</form>
```

While this should not (happy for this to either not find an action, or find the action by provide an empty model).

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/Home/MyMethod?param=MyValue">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I've had a bit of a look at a custom model binder

```
public class FormOnlyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        /*
         * http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/20/how-to-bind-to-custom-objects-in-action-signatures-in-mvc-webapi.aspx
         * Add [ModelBinder(typeof(FormOnlyModelBinder))] to parameter
         * e.g. public ActionResult RetreiveBill([ModelBinder(typeof(CModelBinder))] string token)
         * In controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request you can see the type, and if the data is in q query string or forms data.
         * Just not sure if this is reliable
         */

        throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
}
```

But don't really know where to go from here, or if this is a reliable way of doing this sort of thing.

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem, and you're proposing a solution to the problem hoping we can help you make your solution work.  Why don't you tell us the actual problem you're trying to solve instead?  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Any data supplied to my url in a query string needs to be ignored. It must be in form data.

Comment: .NET provides two different ways to access form data (`Request.Form`) and query string data (`Request.QueryString`). You should be able to easily differentiate between the two on the server side. If you only use `Request.Form` you will effectively ignore the query string arguments.

Comment: @jsve thanks for that, I've hacked something together using the Request

Comment: Wouldn't the FromBody attribute work for this scenario?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx  So `MyMethod([FromBody] string param)`

Comment: @PeteGO I will look into your suggestion, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @PeteGO that does not seems to work, I still get the model populated when the data is in the query string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model binding process in MVC takes into account something called **Value Providers**. These are implementations of the interface `IValueProvider` and there are a few of them which look at different data sources: `FormValueProvider`, `RouteDataValueProvider`, `QueryStringValueProvider`, `HttpFileCollectionValueProvider`.

By default the model binding process will take them all into account, but there are ways to restrict which ones will be used.

- Manually invoke the model binding process specifying which value provider should be used

  ```
  public ActionResult MyMethod()
  {
      var model = new MyModel();
      if (TryUpdateModel(model, new FormValueProvider(this.ControllerContext)))
      {
          //proceed with post action                
      }
      //validation errors, display same form
      return View(model);
  }
  ```
- Add a parameter of type `FormCollection` to your controller action, and manually invoke the model binding using that parameter as value provider. `FormCollection` implements `IValueProvider` by only looking at the form parameters, so it is the same as the option above (but saves you from having to create the value provider instance)

  ```
  public ActionResult MyMethod(FormCollection formData)
  {
      var model = new MyModel();
      if (TryUpdateModel(model, formData))
      {
          //proceed with post action                
      }
      //validation errors, display same form
      return View(model);
  }
  ```
- Create a model binder that only uses the `FormValueProvider` as its value provider. This allows you to write the controller action method as you normally would (without having to manually invoke the model binding)

  ```
  public class FormOnlyModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder
  {
      public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
      {            
          ModelBindingContext newBindingContext = new ModelBindingContext()
          {
              ModelMetadata = bindingContext.ModelMetadata,
              ModelName = bindingContext.ModelName,
              ModelState = bindingContext.ModelState,
              PropertyFilter = bindingContext.PropertyFilter,
              FallbackToEmptyPrefix = bindingContext.FallbackToEmptyPrefix,
              ValueProvider = new FormValueProvider(controllerContext),                
          };

          return base.BindModel(controllerContext, newBindingContext);
      }
  }
  ```

All these options will have the same effect. I would use the second option only if I had this requirement on a very particular action, in any other case I would probably use the custom model binder.

Comment: Great explaination! I was having no Idea about ValueProviders. Thank you very much...

Comment: @Daniel J.G. thanks for this explanation, this is the sort of solution I was hoping for. I was digging through the ModelBindingContext in the IModelBinder.BindModel method and could see these different providers, but I just didn't know what to do with them.

Comment: @Daniel J.G. I was unable to get the tryupdatemodel to work and my model is just a string (I think this may be why), but was able to use the FormCollection directly to find my model value. This worked well, thank you